# Using 1 Active X Button to Import Data From Another Workbook and Do Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if we could create one button that could do 2 activity.
What I want to do here is:
first, to be able to import data by browsing file from another workbook and copy the data to Sheet 1.
Second, I want to be able to browse file but don't copy it. Instead, do Vlookup certain lookup value to Sheet 1.

This is my current code, but idk how to do the second activity without copying the data to another sheet first.

code to import and copy data by browse:

```
Sub ImportDataWil2()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim openbook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    openbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:BC3000").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WK WIL 2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    openbook.Close False
End If
```

Code to do second activity:

```
Sub ImportData()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim openbook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", Filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx),*.xlsx")
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    openbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:BC3000").Copy
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("temporary")
Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Columns("F:K")

Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("WK WIL 2")
Dim dlRow As Long
dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To dlRow
    dws.Cells(i, "BK").Value = Application.VLookup(dws.Cells(i, "BK").Value, srg, 55, 0)
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If it's not possible please kindly tell me that it is not. Thank you in advance!